# Download shapes from leaflet map

Tags: javascript, download, leaflet, geospatial

I have online access to a leaflet map, but cannot reach the authors. Is there a way to download shapes from this map (to shp, geojson, etc.)?

I thought of running some leaflet-related javascript code in browser console, but I couldn't find any relevant commands in the documentation.

Comment: You need to get access to the leaflet map or a layergroup variable, else you can not export it

Comment: @FalkeDesign What do you mean by "get access"? I can view it in my browser.

Comment: can you share the link to the site? I mean that you need to get access to the variable of the map in the console. So that you have access to the function of `L.map` variable

Comment: @FalkeDesign http://mapa-kodow-pocztowych.pl/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look into the dev tools of the link you posted, what you'll find is that the shapes you see there are actually part of a raster tile layer:

[image]

Looking into the source code (sources tab), you can see that they're added with this code:

```js
 L.TileLayer.Codes = L.TileLayer.extend({
        getTileUrl: function(coords) {
            return "http://mapa-kodow-pocztowych.pl/tiles/" + ((coords.x + 10 * coords.y) % 100) + '/' + coords.z + '-' + coords.x + '-' + coords.y + '.png';
        },
        getAttribution: function() {
            return 'Code Map &copy; RoboLabs, <a href ="mailto:admi' + 'n@mapa-kodow-pocztow' + 'ych.pl">email</a>';
        }
  });
```

Looks like those tiles are being served by the same server that's serving the webpage.  Again in the sources tab:

[image]

This means there's no good way to know where the data from these tiles came from, or trace them back to their original shapefile sources (as far as I can tell).  Sorry.  You'd have to contact the page author and ask them for their source data.